# Animating ngView content sequentially instead of concurrently

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

According to Angular 1.2 ngView docs "The enter and leave animation occur concurrently", so the time-lapse of the ngView update procedure goes something like

> add new content > animate entering / leaving one > remove old content

Is there a way how to do it sequentially instead of simultaneously – first removing the old, and just then adding the new one?

> animate leaving one > remove old content > add new content > animate entering one

My point here is that my Ctrl of added (entering) content is firing up another events/animations and the previous content of the ngView is interfering with them. Or is there  a way how to fire an event after entering/laving animation finishes (from the scope of controller)?

Comment: You couldn't, new and old content will both be in DOM tree when animation start. You may need to find a alternative way. However, I think you can achieve something like this `add new content > animate leaving one > remove old content > animate entering one`.

Comment: Well, i've found out that all i'm gonna need is to listen for a "animationend" event, but is there some default angular-style way to catch it on view's entering content? I think it should be possible by extending ngView directive, but…

Comment: There is some way for angular to detect animation end. If you use CSS transition, you can listen to `TransitionEnd` event on animated element (pay attention to vendor prefix). If you use JS animation, you can return a `function` in `app.animation()` module. If sounds like what you want, I can post a answer in detail below. Or you can ask another question with you new requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS3 property [`animation-delay`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-delay.asp) should solve this problem in the most cases. Just delay the fading in animation.

If the animation is more complex you could also think about using CSS [`@keyframes`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp).

Comment: Thanks, that could be useful, but as i've mentioned, it not only about the animations, there are other script triggered by the controller, who needs to wait for the animations to stop. And yes, i can wrap them by some timeouts, but no, it's kind a nasty and not very maintainable for future changes.

Comment: I can image. I think the idea behind the Angular animation component was, to be compatible with the old way things worked in Angular and, if the browser does not support animations, there will be no delay, when switching elements.